# Using a mongodb lookup whilst iterating through a list with morphia in java

Tags: java, mongodb, list, aggregation, morphia

There are 2 collections in my MongoDB.

Details1 (Contains the details for object1 and object2)
Details2 (contains the details for object2 and object3)

The java objects are Essentially Object1 with a list of Object2. 
Object 3 is separate.

Object1 contains an attribute called List
Object 2 contains the fields to link to object 3 in the other collection.

Currently my Dao goes ..... get object 1
Iterates through the list object2's inside object 1. 
get object 3 using the info from object 2.

I need to turn this into 1 single mongodb query.

DAO for object 1 = Get object 1 : -

```
  Query<FclDetail> query =
                this.createQuery()
                        .field(GROUP_ACCOUNT_NO).equal(requestData.getGroupAccountNo())
                        .field(OFFICE_ID).equal(requestData.getOfficeId())
                        .field(AC_SYS_ID).equal(requestData.getAcSysId());
```

Service  : -

```
 FclDetail fclDetail = fclDao.getFclDetails(request.getRequestData());
 FundIfchFacility fundIfchFacility = serviceMapper.map(fclDetail);
 fundIfchFacility.getBsLmStructureNodeList().parallelStream().forEach((bsLmStructureNode) -> {
            FclCliDetail fclCliDetail = fclCliDetailDao.getFclCliDetails(bsLmStructureNode.getNodeInstanceId(),bsLmStructureNode.getStructureCode());}
```

2nd DAO Call : -

```
        Query<FclCliDetail> query = this.createQuery()
                .field(STRUCTURE_CODE)
                .equal(strCde)
                .field(NODE_INSTANCE_ID)
                .equal(ndeItaId);
```

how do I unwind or merge both of these queries to make it look for an object .... find the object .... go through the list inside the object .... and then lookup the other collection with the additional information on those objects.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an aggregation with a [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/).